# Advice on writing math equations into code

Tags: php, algorithm, math

I'm a self taught developer (about 3 years now), and I want to improve my development skills by learning how to write math equations into code.

It's something that continues to bother me, I see many books and articles accompanied by glowing math equations, which genuinely look really interesting. I can read parts of them (multiplication, division, decimals, sigma, variables) but I have troubles when going off to implement them in code.

For example, how would one go about getting started to understand these kind of equations: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manhattan_distance and going off to write them in code?

Any recommendations of places to get started? Is it not the code issue, but lack of fundamental math understanding? I'm willing to listen and read, since I feel this ability is really important for a developer to have.

Comment: If you just want to know what the symbols mean, there's Wikipedia's [List of mathematical symbols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols). But if you want to understand the concepts behind them ... well, if you can teach yourself programming, you can teach yourself math!

Comment: Ah, this helps a lot, thank you! I appreciate the tip, is there any specific math direction I should head off to learn? *seeing as there are so many branches like algebra, calculus, statistics...*

Comment: http://www.amazon.co.uk/Mathematics-Physics-Programmers-Danny-Kodicek/dp/1435457331

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
I can read parts of them (multiplication, division, decimals, sigma, variables)
but I have troubles when going off to implement them in code.
```

Well, the crucial thing I guess is that you need to be able to break down the formula you're interested into its component pieces, and if you can understand how to code those pieces individually, you are in a position to then glue them back together in the form of code.

Let us take as an example the Manhattan distance between two points in two-dimensional space with a fixed `(x, y)` coordinate system. You want to write a function that will take two points and give you the Manhattan distance between those points. Let's forgo the use of object-oriented concepts here and just assume that you have four input variables:

```
x1, the x-coordinate of the first point
y1, the y-coordinate of the first point
x2, the x-coordinate of the second point
y2, the y-coordinate of the second point
```

So our function will be like

```
function mdistance (x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    ???
}
```

What should the insides of the function (the function body) look like? Now we inspect the mathematical formula that we want to rewrite as code. Wikipedia's version (under "Formal description") treats the case of arbitrary dimensions - we can do this too, but for now we're considering the 2-dimensional case only. So their `n` is 2 as far as we are concerned, and we want to compute `|x1 - x2| + |y1 - y2|`. That is the result of losing the sigma notation in favour of an expression describing a sum with two summands. But we still haven't worked out how `|a - b|` can be expressed in computer code.

So now the function could look like

```
function mdistance (x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    return bars(x1, x2) + bars(y1, y2);
}
```

And that, as far as it goes, is fine, because we've isolated the thing we don't yet know how to do as another function, called `bars()`. Once we define `bars()`, the function `mdistance()` will work just fine, assuming of course that our definition for `bars()` is sensible. So the problem is just to define `bars()`. By breaking the problem into its component parts, we've made our job easier, because we just have to make each part work - which is simpler than making everything work at once.

So how should `bars()` be defined? Well, `|a - b|` just expresses the idea "the absolute value of `a - b`". PHP has a built-in function for the absolute value of a real number; it is `abs()`. So we define `bars()` like this:

```
function bars (a, b) {
    return abs(a - b);
}
```

Now our function `mdistance()` will work just the way we want.

Comment: Amazing. Thanks for taking your time to write this, it really helped.

At this point I'm understanding it's like decoding a program to understand how it works, as you mentioned. Assuming this kind of ability comes with practice and learning, I'll be off trying to code up simple math algorithms. Would you have any that you think are simple to get started with?

Comment: Well, if you want to get practice converting mathematical expressions into code, elementary statistics provides quite a lot of material. Try coding functions that will compute the mean, variance, and standard deviation of a set of real numbers. (You will probably want to work with PHP's array functions to get this to work.) For a challenge, try writing a function that will compute the product moment correlation coefficient of two sets of data. (To do this you really will want to break the task down into smaller tasks, because the formula for the PMCC is large and complex.)

Answer (score 0):

Use `sin(),cos(),sqrt()`.

For the vectors you need `array()` and for the sum you need a loop (`for`/`foreach`). Vector length = array length, use `count`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can write mathematical ecuations into your code using mathematical API´s. For example in java there is Math for this purpose. Or you can write your own methods(functions) that will be able to perform these operations... let see the ecuation in the posted link. The first ecuation: Suma of absolute values of difference of pi and qi (p with index i). pi and qi you can store them inside an array. Then for the absolute value you can write your own function that is able to do this operation, for example(I used C/C++ style syntax):

```
int absoluteValue(int number){
     if (number < 0) return number = number * (-1);
     else return number;
}
```

And for suma too: its only a simple for() cycle. If you have more difficult mathematical operations, of course it is more difficult to implement them.
 You simply have to write to PC step by step instructions how to perform the operation. Exactly how do you, when you are calculating something.

Hope this was helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to evaluate an expression (involving mathematical functions, operations, etc.) then the procedure is usually fairly straightforward (however complicated in code and computer steps).  We might call this explicit mathematics, when an equation's left-hand side is computed by evaluation of the right-hand side.

But equations in mathematical articles can have an entirely implicit meaning and utility.  For example a differential equation does not often give a programmer an obvious method to find its solution.  These kinds of task require a programmer to supplement the equations found in the literature with some knowledge of numerical analysis.